# Macro with Application.OnTime Only Works When worksheet is Opened

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Worksheet that requires a macro to run every day at 10AM.  The code only works when I have a specific worksheet opened, but doesn’t when another worksheet is open. Can somebody please help me?

Code in Module:

```
Sub SendC()

  Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "SendC"

  **Rest of my code **

End Sub
```

Code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.OnTime TimeValue("10:00:00"), "SendC"

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Worksheet open"? Like a tab/worksheet active vs a different worksheet in the same workbook?

Comment: I mean when the worksheet is indeed activated - if i click on another worksheet tab and hence another worksheet opens the code doesn't run at 10AM.

Answer (score 0):

VBA code lives embedded in a host document - in the case of Excel, a macro-enabled Workbook file.

By closing the workbook that contains the code, you terminate whatever VBA code was running in that workbook.

You can make VBA code run at application-level, by making an Excel add-in: the code still lives embedded in a host document, but that host document is loaded along with Excel, and remains loaded as long as that Excel instance is running.

Save your VBA project as an Excel add-in, then close everything, bring up Excel again and load the add-in: `Workbook_Open` will run once as the add-in is loaded, and then your `SendC` macro will be invoked at 10AM for as long as you leave Excel running.

Comment: Silly question but how do i save my VBA code as an Excel add-in?

Comment: @VBANewbee you don't save the VBA code, you save the workbook that contains it. So, *Save As*, then change the file type to "Microsoft Excel Add-In".

Comment: thanks for your help again. I've saved the Workbook as an add-in. When reopening Excel and loading the add-inn nothing happens. I've also loaded the .xlsm file and the add-in right after, but no change.

Comment: Make sure the add-in is [stored in a trusted location](https://superuser.com/a/1107370/165271).